# posting $scope variable with $http

Tags: angularjs

**JS**

```
$scope.SendData = function () {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/ajouterPr',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {'nom':$scope.nom, 'poste':$scope.poste}
    }

    $http(req).then(function(){
        alert('success');
    }, function(){
        alert(error.error);
    });
};
```

Please, can anyone tell me what's wrong with that!! Why I can't use $scope.var in my data?

Comment: Is the `$scope` initialized in the controller where the function is?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What actually does happen? Are there any errors? What does the console show?

Comment: $scope.nom="";
    $scope.poste="";
    $scope.SendData = function ($scope) {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/ajouterPr',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {'nom':$scope.poste, 'poste':$scope.nom}
        }

        $http(req).then(function(){
            alert('success');
            }, function(){
            alert(error.error);
            });
    };

Comment: angular.js:13283 TypeError: Cannot read property 'poste' of undefined
    at m.$scope.SendData (app.js:35)

Comment: @IssamDalhoumi Try the answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$scope` parameter from the `SendData` function. You don't need to add it as it is already available in context of the controller, *and* by adding it you're creating a new variable named `$scope` inside of `SendData` which is undefined because you're not passing anything in when calling it.

```
$scope.SendData = function () {
   var req = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost:8080/addPr',
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       data: {'nom':$scope.poste, 'poste':$scope.name}
   }
    $http(req).then(function(){
           alert('success');
        }, function(){
           alert(error.error);
    });
};
```

## EDIT

Try making the `$scope` variables into a object. You also need to make your `ng-model="foo.poste"` and `ng-model="foo.name"`

```
$scope.foo = {
    poste : "poste",
    name: "name"   
}
$scope.SendData = function () {
   var req = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost:8080/addPr',
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       data: {'nom':$scope.foo.poste, 'poste':$scope.foo.name}
   }
    $http(req).then(function(){
           alert('success');
        }, function(){
           alert(error.error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Good catch, I missed that in the borked code formatting.

Comment: @IssamDalhoumi You _have_ to define "doesn't work." Did the error change? What is the error now?

Comment: Where from do you call the `$scope.SendData` ?

Comment: @IssamDalhoumi in your last comment, which is terribly confusing, you _still_ have the `$scope` param in your `SendData` signature...

Comment: @IssamDalhoumi are you inserting the info to `$scope.poste` and `$scope.name` at HTML side?

Comment: In this case ( $scope.nom="";
    $scope.poste="";
    $scope.SendData = function ($scope) {...}) I got this error (  angular.js:13283 TypeError: Cannot read property 'poste' of undefined at m.$scope.SendData (app.js:35)  )  on google chrome console    . BUT when I remove $scope from the parameter of my function i get no errors but the data is not registred on my database.... I call my function  from my button through (   ng-click="SendData()"   )

Comment: Ok wait a sec might be a `.` rule

Comment: please notice that when i post this data example it works**********  data: {'name':'steeve', 'poste':'a'}

Comment: @IssamDalhoumi could you add the HTML to your question where you call the SendData function?

Comment: @Konkko        <input  ng-model="foo.name" type="text">
                                <select  ng-model="foo.poste">......
                                <button ng-click="SendData()">

Comment: What does `console.log(req.data)` between `var req =...` and `$http` give you?

Comment: console.log(req.data) : Object {name: "steeve", poste: "e"} for  example

Comment: but data is not inserted in database that is the problem!

Comment: @IssamDalhoumi Check from `data: {'nom':$scope.foo.poste, 'poste':$scope.foo.name}` that the variable names are equal to the ones at the backend side should it be   `data: {'name':$scope.foo.poste, 'poste':$scope.foo.name}`?

Comment: Glad to hear :) Happy coding